# How to use XML data of SQL table column and perform tasks based on tag values

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need some help. I am suppose to get XML data from column of a table. The XML data has many tags. One of the tag contains values like

```
<Code date= 30/03/2013> 
<apr id =1> -2 </apr>
<rdv id =2> 1 </rdv>
</code>
```

I need to run a particular task which checks the date. Like if `today's date= (Code date -2)` or

```
today's date = (code date + 1)
```

run a mailer task.

How should I go about it ? Please forgive me for the XML data format. I am naive in XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create 2 [variables](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-variables/) to store the XML column Date value and other one to get the current date .To write an expression ,select the variable ,right click on it .In the properties windows Set `EvaluateAsExpression =true` and write the `expression`

  ```
    Name          DataType   Expression 
   ExecDate       DateTime
   CurrentDate    DateTime    GETDATE()
  ```
- Use `Execute SQL Task` .Set `Resultset` to `Single Row` and write the following code to read the date value from the XML column in your table

  ```
  SELECT
  convert(datetime,XMLData.value('(/Code/@date)[1]', 'varchar(10)'),103) as PkgDate
  from yourTable
  ```

Demo in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5137/5)

- In the `resultset tab`  map the output from the above sql query with the variable `ExecDate`

  ```
  Result Name    Variable Name
  PkgDate           ExecDate
  ```
- Put another Task or component Ex `SEND Mail TASK` after `Execute SQL Task` and write an expression in the [Precedence Constraint](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-precedence-constraints-in-sql-server-integration-services/).

  ```
  Expression : @ExecDate==@CurrentDate
  ```

Only when the Date value from the XML column matches with the Current Date which is stored in the variable `@CurrentDate` then only the other components after `Execute SQL Task` will execute .

```
today's date= (Code date -2) or today's date = (code date + 1) run a mailer task.
```

In order to perform the above expression ,you need to change the sql code in `Execute SQL Task`

To get CodeDate +1

```
    SELECT
    Dateadd(day,1,convert(datetime,XMLData.value('(/Code/@date)[1]', 'varchar(10)'),103)) as PkgDate
    from yourTable
```

I don't have the SSIS environment to test it now but this is how you should be doing it

Comment: Thank you praveen. I did get an idea of how to proceed with my problem.